# Why does Scala occasionally fall back to Java objects?

Tags: java, scala, language-interoperability

I'm almost certain that this question has been asked before, but I'm missing the right words to find it.

```
scala> Seq[Any]( 3, 3.4 )
res0: Seq[Any] = List(3, 3.4)

scala> res0( 1 ).getClass
res1: Class[_] = class java.lang.Double

scala> Seq( 3, 3.4 )
res2: Seq[Double] = List(3.0, 3.4)

scala> res2( 1 ).getClass
res3: Class[Double] = double
```

Why is Scala handling my `Double` input as `java.lang.Double` within a `Seq[Any]` but keeps it as `scala.Double` when working with a `Seq[AnyRef]`? Is there a way to prevent this behavior and instead always use the Scala types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala's `Double` corresponds to Java's `double` but may get autoboxed and unboxed if needed and it becomes `java.lang.Double` when it gets autoboxed. In practice, collections require autoboxing of primitive variables.

The types of collections you declare get inferred based on the value assigned to them if the type is not declared explicitly. The difference between the two declarations in the question is that for `Seq(value1,value2,...)` type inferrence tries to find the "best" type, comes up with `Seq[Double]` and then inteprets `value1`, `value2` and so on based on this type (Scala `Double`). If you declare the type explicitly as `Seq[Any]`, type inferrence is not run (since you gave the type yourself) and so the values `value1`, `value2` etc. are not "forced" into being interpreted as being of a fixed type.

Since `Seq` is a collection, primitives are not allowed and must be autoboxed, so Java's `double` can't fit in while `java.lang.Double` can. The logic which tries to hide boxing and unboxing for `Seq[Double]` and transparently interchanges the primitive and the object doesn't come into play. Actually, in a `Seq[Any]`, each element may be of a different type which means such boxing and unboxing can't work in the general case (in your example, `res0(0).getClass` is an `Integer` in contrast to `res2(0).getClass` which is a Double).

So, essentially, if you don't declare the type explicitly, the type inferrence kicks in and first tries to find a common type for all elements of the collection and then casts all elements into that type while with the collection type parameter specified explicitly, no such thing takes place and all values' types are interpreted "raw".

Comment: But a literal, as `3` for instance, is an `Int <: AnyVal <: Any`. And what I've been asking for is a `Seq[Any]`. So on the first glance it should not be a problem to maintain the Scala type. Why does the boxing become necessary?

Comment: @Taig Boxing is needed because collections work on objects. Scala tries to hide the fact that there are primitive types and objects but at JVM level this distinction does exist. Since Scala runs on the JVM, it is subject to this limitation. It tries to hide it but it not always can. The JVM doesn't have the equivalent of `AnyVal`, so inside the collection, the hierarchy only looks like `java.lang.Integer <: Object`.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is boxing. Because the first is a `Seq[Any]`, any primitives in it will come back in the boxed form. In the second case, because the type is `Seq[Double]`, access to the members will be automatically unboxed (but will still be stored boxed in the `Seq`).

Trying to get the runtime class for primitives is bound to cause all sorts of problems. Try not needing to use `getClass`.